# Web Deploy giving 404, handler missing?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, deployment, iis-8.5

On a brand new install of Server 2012 R2, I want to set up Web Deploy in IIS for one click publishing from the development machine.

So I enabled the web management service and installed Web Deploy 3.5, created a .PublishSettings file, and attempted to publish a test site.

It keeps giving a 404 not found error. I examined the http handlers and saw that /msdeploy.axd has no handler and the default *.axd HttpNotFoundHandler is taking effect.

What installation step did I miss? Should I manually add the handler? I don't know what type it would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I needed to first install the (separate) Web Deployment Tool, then go through the Web Deploy process to create the .PublishSettings, then it worked like a charm.

Still no msdeploy.axd handler, so I'm not sure what magic I'm missing.

Would be nice if Web Deploy considered the Web Deployment Tool a dependancy, as well as enabling the web management service. Or at least some documentation. Web Platform Installer can be confusing.